# Dynamically monkey patch a python 2.7 class

Tags: python, python-decorators, monkeypatching

Wondering if anyone has a good way to dynamically inspect a class for its function types and then dynamically monkey patch a decorator onto some of those functions.

I'm trying this but not getting the results I expect. Walking through the methods in the class seems to be working but doing the monkey patch itself seems to fail.

```
def decorator(callable):
    pass

class Test(object):
    def foo1(self):
        return self.bar()

    def foo2(self):
        return self.blah()

    def foo3(self):
        return 0

for x,y in Test.__dict__.items():
        if type(y) == FunctionType:
            Test.x = decorator(Test.x)
```

Comment: This approach of adding a decorator dynamically is totally valid. I would also prefer a better syntax by Python but for the moment it should be fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course `Test.x` does not exist and this will raise `AttributeError`. You can use `setattr` for this. Also `x.__dict__` looks ugly to me, I'd use `vars(x)` instead.

```
for x,y in vars(Test).items():
    if type(y) == FunctionType:
        setattr(Test, x, decorator(y))
```